# how to create a pop up window with multiple options and user can choose more than one option in android(Java)

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have attached the pic of what I need to achieve. When i clicked on a textview I need to show a pop up window as the above pic. Where user can select one or multiple options . I created an xml with multiple text views and inflating that layout in a dialog. What I need is how can user select multiple options and selected options should be highlighted. and how to dismiss the dialog.

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/alert_bg"
    android:backgroundTint="#EDECEC"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/threeyears"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:alpha=".4"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="3 years and under"/>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fouryears"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text=" 4 - 6 years"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sevenyears"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="7 - 9 years"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tenyears"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="10 - 12 years"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirteenyears"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="13 - 15 years"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sixteenyears"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="16 - 18 years"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nochildrens"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="No Childrens"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**My Java Code**

```
parentstatustextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        parentaldialog = new Dialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), R.style.CustomDialog);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.parentalstatus, null);
        parentaldialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        parentaldialog.setCancelable(true);
        parentaldialog.setContentView(view1);
        parentaldialog.show();
        final TextView threeyears = view1.findViewById(R.id.threeyears);
        final TextView fouryears = view1.findViewById(R.id.fouryears);
        final TextView seveenyears = view1.findViewById(R.id.sevenyears);


        threeyears.setOnClickListener(this);
        fouryears.setOnClickListener(this);
        seveenyears.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close the dialog with an `accept` button or something similar. On item click, you should mark it to feedback the user (bold, change color or use a checkbox) and store its status on an array (for example). When the user clicks on the `accept` button, take the selected items from the array.

Comment: Hi Daniel there is no accept button or check box . In the above pic design is same. There are 3 selected text

Comment: @LahariAreti on what state/situation user will dismiss the dialog?what is your requirement?

Comment: @Wini after User selection of the options need to dismiss

Comment: @LahariAreti when user will select all the options then it will automatically dismiss is that what you want..or when user will 3 options then it will get dismiss?need clarification

Comment: @Wini User can select 1 or many options. User may select only 1 option. or user may select 2 options. After selecting the options need to get selected options and dismiss the pop up